# How to increase DPI of vncviewer?

Tags: hdpi, dpi, vncviewer

vncviewer doesn't scale with the DPI of your display, I can't make out anything on this tiny thing:
[image: vncviewer GUI]

I'm having eye strain from that. The `GDK_SCALE=x` or `GDK_DPI_SCALE=x` approaches don't work.

How to increase the DPI of vncviewer?

Comment: It seems that it does not use a recent version of GTK or Qt. It is a proprietary software, and there is nothing much we can do about it. Check out free alternatives https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Clients

Comment: Well the official Ubuntu vncviewer xtightvvncviewer is even worse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysf5U.png

Comment: `xtightvvncviewer` is not "official". It was recommended in that website ages ago.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another app. Can you try that?

Comment: The GUI scales properly but it can't connect to `vncserver`, hence has no funcitonality.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [vinagre](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Vinagre?action=show&redirect=Vinagre), which is a VNC viewer for GNOME desktop. It uses gtk3, and should scale properly.

```
sudo apt install vinagre
```

[image]

2. Alternatively, install GNOME Connections with flatpak.

```
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Connections
```

Comment: It scales properly but it can't connect to `vncserver` - connection is closed immediately without a proper error message.